# Content elements as inline elements in a content element

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

My idea is to build a content element with some inline elements. No big problem if the inline elements derive from an other table ... But i want to use other content elements - like news, where you can add content elements to the detail page as inline elements.

The problem is the colPos value - if it is the value of the current column the inline elements are shown twice: once as standalone element and once as inline (it works in news only because news eintries are normally on sysfolders). If i force other values for the colPos entry (like 999 oder -10) i get in the backend always INVALID VALUE ("-10")

Any idea? Is there a possibility?

It would be a nice solution for e.g. a accordion or tabs.

Thanks!

---

My solution:

There were too many arguements against content elements inline a content element. So i solved it with a content element with inline elements from an other table - the same way as mask would solve the problem. It works for me without the problems which mentioned in the answers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRRE tt_content to tt_content is *notoriously* error prone; there are concerns not only with the colPos column but also with recursion. I very strongly advise against it. It breaks translation ability, has problems with workspaces and it potentially treats file references of the children incorrectly.

That said: you can add virtual colPos values by modifying the TCA of `tt_content.colPos` to add selection values that match your chosen colPos value.

Comment: Too many arguments against it ... i give up :-) Thanks! I will sign this answer as correct.

Comment: I only know these limitations because I've made the same mistake myself and can now warn others to not repeat my mistakes. It can be done, it just has a *lot* of drawbacks and peculiarities ;)

Answer (score 0):

The extension [Gridelements](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements/) does this. Why dont you use it?

Comment: Gridelements had the same issue that records have been shown twice but the issue was solved last year (by description of the commits I couldn't find the right one).

Comment: Two reasons: 
- i need the possibility in tx_news to use content elements. This seems not working with gridelements - i cant select my defined grids in tx_news.
- i need only very simple ce as inlne elements (1 line of text with link). Grids are huge in the backend and clutters the work space for the editors. With inline elements it would be much more user friendly. 
If it doesnt work i will use grids of course.

Comment: If its just 1 line of text with a link then extend tx_news and add an text input and a link field? Adding content elements is much more work.

Comment: I explained it wrong ... i need all Content Elements in News plus one lonely gridelement with undefined number of lines with links in it. Nicely between some other content elements ...